# Air 3.0 + bundle + autoupdate + Error# 16828

Tags: adobe, air, auto-update

I've got the following error while updating my Air 3.0 application packaged with the bunlde option :

**An unexpected error occurred. Error# 16828**

Here is my update.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/1.0">
        <versionNumber>4.2.1</versionNumber>
        <url>http://myserver.com/update/MyApp-4.2.1.air</url>
        <description>
                <text xml:lang="en">Update</text>
                <text xml:lang="fr">Update</text>
        </description>
</update>
```

Any ideas ?

Cheers

Damien

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdaterUI.html

downloadError

16828   Cannot update application, usually because the application is running in the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL).

Answer (score 0):

Hi export your main air file as a air file not as an EXE and that should solve your problem. If both your update file and normal air is .air this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Jaco, if I export the main installer as a .air file does that mean I need to give instructions for installing Air separately? The .exe installs it for people if they don't have it which is kind of helpful, I gather I'd be missing that?